# Font looks different when site is server over https

Tags: css, http, https, google-webfonts

Hi there I'm running into a problem

when website is viewed with https everything is made bold

https://www.healthinsurance.uk.net/

when its viewed with out the bold has gone?

I've never seen this before

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a “debug my website for me” non-question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Everything isn't made bold but you get your backup font (`sans-serif`) instead of the one you wanted.

This happens because the font you are trying to load from Google Webfonts is hardcoded to regular http in your `style.css`.

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=News+Cycle:400,700);
```

Change that line to the following and it should choose http or https based on the currently loaded page.

```
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=News+Cycle:400,700);
```

Comment: You beat me by 8 seconds. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks all sorted! : )

Comment: I think that typically, browsers show a warning message in the console if they refuse to load an "unsafe" resource. Maybe you could add that it's smart to look for clues there.