# Web server not rendering Google font

Tags: html, css, fonts

I've published my ASP.NET MVC5 website to my server and noticed the font is incorrect.

On my local host it works as expected. On every HTML page, I have the following in head `head` tags

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300italic,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

And in my CSS I have

```
body {
    letter-spacing: .05em;    
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    color: #4f4f4f;
}
```

A quick search within the project shows this is the only time I use `font`.

I'm also aware there is no 'back up font', but that is not relevant.

[Font looks different when site is server over https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287870/font-looks-different-when-site-is-server-over-https) didn't help as I'm already using https

When I try the font in [typecast](http://typecast.com/preview/google/Lato) I can see that the localhost is rendering the font correctly where as my server is not.

The website is not using SSL

Within Chrome, I open the dev tools and in Network I can see

```
css?family=Lato:400,300italic,700,300   GET   200  stylesheet   MyPage:13   920 B   263 ms
```

I've also checked the rendered HTML and CSS, and although there is some minification, the syntax looks the same.

Why will this font not render on my web server.

Comment: remove the https from the statement. This way the browser will determine what method to use to access the google site.

Comment: @jeff, how odd - that is exactly what was wrong with the post I cite, yet, it works. Please move to an answer